# Как вычислить знак оператора в строке?

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет. Есть нижеприведенный код. Моя задача разбить term (двучлен) на два одночлена. Метод IndexOf проверяет term на наличие знаков ('+', '-', '*', '/') и делает он это именно в таком порядке, как перечислено в массиве operators. Сначала он находит -3**(+)**3 и присваивает arithmeticSign = '+', затем находит **(-)**3+3 и пересваивает arithmeticSign = '-', а мне-то нужно, что бы он присваивал '+', так как плюс является оператором, а не минус. Как мне это реализовать?

**WrathOfFlame** решил эту проблему. Следующим образом:

```
// term это строка двучлен, например -3+2
    for (int i = 1; i < term.Length; i++) 
        {
        if (term[i] == '+' || term[i] == '-' || term[i] == '*' || term[i] == '/')
           {
        // Если перед знаком число, то это и будет моим оператором.
           if (term[i - 1] != 0 && Char.IsDigit(term, i - 1)) 
              {
               OperatorSign = term[i];

               monomials = term.Split(term[i]);

  // Operand1,Operand2 свойства, которые дают доступ к полям operand1,operand2
               Operand1 = monomials[0]; 
               Operand2 = monomials[1];

               if (monomials[0] == " " || monomials[1] == " ")
                  {
                   ErrReport();
                  }
               }
            }
        }
```

Появилась ***новая проблема***, а именно с двучленами такого вида: -x-y или +x+y.
При таких двучленах, эта строка заносит "monomials = term.Split(term[i]);"
3 элемента в массив(monomials[0]="", monomials[1]="x", monomials[2]="y") , а мне нужно два. Как бы разбить строку именно на том месте, где вышеупомянутый цикл находит оператор?

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: А почему бы не написать нормальный лексер? Представьте себе, что у вас выражения немного сложнее, например, `-3 - -3` — будете специальный `if` писать каждый раз?

Comment: VladD, а что за лексер такой? Я в этом деле зеленый. Поясни, желательно с небольшим примером, если несложно.

Comment: @Аристарх: лексер — это лексический анализатор. Научить писать их в двух словах не могу, это довольно большая тема. Вот вам [пример простого лексера](http://stackoverflow.com/a/673657/276994) на C#. Вам стоит разобраться в нём, умение написать парсер всегда пригодится.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо Вам за помощь. Ну, как я понял, это далеко нетривиальная тема, как минимум для меня. Рано или поздно, дай Бог, разберусь в этом деле.

Comment: @Аристарх: Да, тема нетривиальная и полезная. Если вы не знакомы с ней, сейчас делайте как получается, но обязательно разберитесь с этой темой позже.

Comment: @VladD, благодарю за совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD:

```
// monomial1 - строка, первый член
// monomial2 - строка, второй член
// term - строка двучлен, например -3+2

monomial1 = "";
monomial2 = "";
int index = -1; // позиция разделителя

for ( int i = 1; i < term.Length; i++) 
{
    if (term[i] == '+' || term[i] == '-' || term[i] == '*' || term[i] == '/')
    {
        // индекс не выходит за левую границу, т.к. i изначально присвоено значение 1
        if ( Char.IsDigit(term, i - 1))
        {
           OperatorSign = term[i];
           index = i;
           // обрываем цикл, на данный момент у нас есть только первый член
           break;
        }

    }

    // формируем первый член
    monomial1 += term[i];

}

// зная индекс разделителя, формируем второй член

   for ( int i = index+1; i < term.Length; i++) 
   {
        monimial2 += term[i];
   }
```

Знаю, что слегка коряво, но код будет справедлив для всех возможных комбинаций в двучлене. К примеру, ваше решение не работало бы для term = (-)3+(-)3.

Comment: WrathOfFlame, спасибо за ответ. Только не могу понять, что за isdigit?
И term[i] или operations[i]?

Comment: пробегаемся по всей строке: если i-тый элемент один из арифметических знаков, проверяем есть ли перед ним число. Если так - это и есть арифметический знак между числами.
isdigit(char) - проверяет является ли символ числом. (не заметил метки C# в вашем вопросе, идентичная функция в нем есть http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: WrathOfFlame, спасибо тебе, чёткое решение. Правда никак не могу реализовать его, много синтаксических ошибок. Ссылка пустая.

Comment: Я обновлю свой ответ. Код снабжен комментариями.

Comment: WrathOfFlame благодарю тебя за работу. У меня возникла новая проблема, я обновил свой вопрос раньше, чем ты обновил свой ответ -) Ты видел?

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя х и у помещаются в один символ, то можно определить позицию оператора:
Если строка начинается со знака, то оператор на 2-й позиции, от нуля.
Если строка начинается с числа, то оператор на 1-й позиции.

Если х и у больше, чем один символ, то в цикле проходи по строке и записывай первый одночлен, пока i+1 символ не знак. Когда i+1 символ знак, значит ты на последнем символе одночлена. Дальше записываешь второй одночлен, позицию оператора ты уже нашел.

Comment: @iplot спасибо. Попробую это реализовать.